# Storing of Office AddIn settings does not trigger automatic save (dirty flag) in Online Clients

Tags: office365, office-js

We are storing settings via `Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync()`.
In the PowerPoint Online this is not recognized as a change of the document.
So if the user leaves the document "*too early*" or does not change other things the settings are not stored.

To force the automatic save of the document we had to change other content in the document e.g. edit text. Then the AddIn settings are stored too.

***Any tipps how to force the automatic save or dirty flag in online clients when storing addin settings?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a bug in the Add-in implementation, we are actively working on the fix. thanks.

Comment: Who is we? Microsoft Office-Add In developer team?

Comment: yes. we are able to repro it and is investigating the root cause.